# How can I make my bash script wait 30 minutes to run?

Tags: bash

I have a bash script to lock my computer. I want to set it to lock in 30 minutes from right now.

This is my bash script for my mac computer to lock my screen

```
/System/Library/CoreServices/Menu\ Extras/User.menu/Contents/Resources/CGSession -suspend
```

I can execute it with this code

```
sh ~/Documents/Misc/lock_computer
```

Comment: Try `sleep 1800`?  https://linux.die.net/man/1/sleep

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the `sleep 30m` command.

More details here: https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-sleep-bash-scripting/

Comment: I went with this. It's easier than working it out with the `at` command

Comment: @Cauder: You should accept this answer then instead of mine.

Answer (score 1):

```
echo 'sh ~/Documents/Misc/lock_computer' | at 'now + 30 minutes'
```

Comment: I'd like to include it in the script. It works when I just add `at now + 1 minutes` above the line with my command and then use the same sh command. Is that legal in bash?

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. The command string needs to be piped into the `at` command as I've shown in my answer. Putting the `at` command by itself on a line above your command won't do anything. It sounds like you probably need to add the `sleep` command to your script as suggested in another answer instead.

Comment: Do I have the syntax wrong? I use the sh command and this triggers the screen lock in exactly 25 seconds. `sleep 25m && /System/Library/CoreServices/Menu\ Extras/User.menu/Contents/Resources/CGSession -suspend`

Comment: @Cauder: I'm not the one who supplied the `sleep` answer, but that should work. You might look at `man sleep` to see what options are supported. It appears you might be on a Mac and that suffixes such as `m` aren't supported. That would mean that you would use `sleep 1500` which is the number of seconds in 25 minutes.